# Docker mysql_connect(): Can't connect

Tags: php, mysql, docker

Bearing in mind I'm trying to run in a docker environment with php 5.4 due to Kohana PHP MVC being a framework which hasn't been updated and is no longer going to be supported, get following error

```
mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(2) ["file":protected]=> string(64) "/var/www/html/modules/database/classes/kohana/database/mysql.php
```

my docker command is

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 -p 3307:3306 -p 22:22  -v   "/home/me/public_html/project-folder:/var/www/html" ushios/lamp-ubuntu
```

Am I missing something to make it work with the database, thanks

Comment: Why are you doing `-p 3307:3306` ?

Comment: see my previous problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162285/docker-using-mysql

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the latest version of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1):

**It doesn't look like your PHP settings are using the tcp connector.**

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

It seems to be using the **'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'**.
The [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) call defaults to using various PHP settings in absence of parameters.

Check your setting in PHP and the [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) call itself.

My guess is that you either need to:

- Change the default settings
- Add parameters to the mysql_connect call.

As an aside, *mysql_* is depreciated, you should use the *mysqli_* set of calls if possible.

Comment: more than deprecated, it's outright REMOVED in php 7.0

Comment: @hanshenrik, True, though I suspect this projects not going to upgrade past PHP 5.x

Answer (score 1):

Docker file: 
 - docker-php-ext-install mysqli
 - docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

On code:
 Use mysqli_connect instead mysql_connect